# Stable Matching Optimal Strategy Existence

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

There is a famous [stable marriage problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem).

It's well known that the standard algorithm for stable marriage problem proposed by Shapley and Gale is man-optimal, men get a best according to their preferences among all stable matchings.

**truthful game?** Men don't have the incentive to change their preferences because by default they get the "best" woman, however women can achieve a better man but deliberately changing their preferences list (not the true preferences, but just the list) in this case a game is not more truthful, and there is a proven result that there is no any truthful mechanism for the stable matching problem?

**Problem**.The problem is to show that there is *always* a pure Nash equilibrium in the game of stable marriage problem when players can present altered preference list (when the players can lie).

**Ideas**.The intuition is optimal matching exists, and only women should care about altering preference list in the run of Gale-Shapley algorithms. However, women don't know the best possible preference list. Therefore it might take few iteration of the Gale-Shapley algorithm to them to figure out what is the best preference list.

How to show it mathematically rigorous is still a problem. Would appreciate any help.